# c++ template class, initialization () vs {}

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am wondering why I can't initialize an instance of the following template class with **()** instead of **{}** within the scope of another class (C++ 11)? error: expected identifier before numeric constant

```
template <typename T>
class vec3 {

private:

    T   data[3];

public:

    vec3 (T a, T b, T c);
};

template <typename T> 
vec3<T>::vec3 (T a, T b, T c) 
{
    data[0] = a;
    data[1] = b;
    data[2] = c;
}

class whatever {

    vec3 <float> a (1,2,3); // not ok
    vec3 <float> b {1,2,3}; // ok

};

int main () {

    vec3 <float> a (1,2,3); // ok

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initializers using `()` were disallowed in the [**proposal of non-static data member initializers - N2756**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm), for the reasons mentioned by @T.C. in the comment section:

> Unfortunately, this makes initializers of the “`(` *expression-list* `)`”
>   form ambiguous at the time that the declaration is being parsed:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>     int i(x); // data member with initializer
>     // ...
>     static int x;
> };
>
> struct T {
>     int i(x); // member function declaration
>     // ...
>     typedef int x;
> };
> ```
>
> One possible solution is to rely on the existing rule that, if a declaration could be an object or a function, then it’s a function:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>     int i(j); // ill-formed...parsed as a member function,
>               // type j looked up but not found
>     // ...
>     static int j;
> };
> ```
>
> A similar solution would be to apply another existing rule, currently used only in templates, that if T could be a type or
>   something else, then it’s something else; and we can use “typename” if
>   we really mean a type:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>     int i(x); // unabmiguously a data member
>     int j(typename y); // unabmiguously a member function
> };
> ```
>
> **Both of those solutions introduce subtleties that are likely to be misunderstood by many users (as evidenced by the many questions on
>   comp.lang.c++ about why “`int i();`” at block scope doesn’t declare a
>   default-initialized `int`). The solution proposed in this paper is to allow only initializers of the “`=` *initializer-clause*” and “`{` *initializer-list* `}`” forms.**

Answer (score 4):

That's simply a restriction on how class members can be initialised. You can use `{}` or `=` but not `()`.

I don't think there's a particularly compelling justification for the restriction; it's just one of the language's many quirks.

Comment: doesn't it get treated as a function deceleration when used inside of a class?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Only if the things in the `()` can be interpreted as function parameters; in which case it's a function declaration wherever it appears.

Comment: The reason is that the committee wanted NSDMIs to get class-scope lookup just like member initializer lists in constructors, but with class-scope lookup permitting the `()` form makes it difficult to determine whether something is a function declaration or an initializer at the time it is parsed.